# Load Hierarchical list automatically from Hierarchical select option

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I have this Hierarchical taxonomy structure

[image: Phones]

In content type, I have a taxonomy term reference to this vocabulary using Hierarchical List provided by [Hierarchical Select Module](https://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select). When I want to add the content, I get the default Select Option as:

[image: iPhone List]

***(Note the Update Button Above)***. When I hit Update then only I get child terms of **iPhone**

[image]

Now, if I want to select **Nokia** instead of **Apple**

[image: Nokia Phone List]

I **don't** get that ***Update Button***, or I cannot change it until I refresh the page.

Is there any way the Child list *(list in hierarchy)* would load without hitting Update and change whenever I change the Parent list?

**In short :** I want to get rid of ***Update Button*** and load the Hierarchy List automatically when I change the value in the list.

- If I select Apple, the list in the Apple would show.
- If I select Nokia then Phones under Nokia would show without having
  to hit Update or Refresh the Page.

Comment: Instead use simple Hierarchical Select Module. https://drupal.org/project/shs

Comment: does it support exposed filter for views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead use [Simple hierarchical select](https://drupal.org/project/shs) module, It actually load child terms without button.

[image]

> Simple hierarchical select defines a new form widget for taxonomy
>   fields to select a term by "browsing" through the vocabularies
>   hierarchy. The widget is available in node forms and as Views exposed
>   filter.